# Decending order in SQlite android not correct

Tags: sqlite

I have problem when descending order in sqlite,
i have record in field 'kd_people' like this :

```
    P1
    P2
    P3
    P4
    P5
    P10
```

When create query "`select kd_people from people order by kd_people desc`", the result like :

```
    P1
    P10
    P2
    P3
    P4
    P5
```

but i want result like this:

```
    P10
    P5
    P4
    P3
    P2
    P1
```

so how the correct query ? thanks, sorry for my english

Comment: If the strings always start with `P` you could try to extract the numeric part and sort by that.

Comment: Something is very weird if you get the second result using `DESC`. Otherwise, @Henry has the right of it: split the column into `kd_people_prefix` and `kd_people_number`, make sure the latter has numbers and not strings, and `ORDER BY kd_people_prefix DESC, kd_people_number DESC`.

Comment: If you wanted it to sort like a number, why did you store it as text?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to sort numerically rather than alphabetically on the number part of your id.

First, consider storing the data you want to sort on directly in a database column i.e. modify your schema a bit.

If you want to do it in SQL, use `SUBSTR()` to remove the non-numeric prefix, and use `CAST()` to turn the remaining into a number. Example assuming the non-numeric prefix is always just 1 character:

```
... ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(kd_people,2) AS INTEGER) DESC
```

(The example you posted seemed to be an `ASC` sort rather than `DESC`.)